# I want to display a simple 'hello' message over the server using django in vscode but it says page not found

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I want to display a simple hello in the server but receiving an error as Page not found.

here are my code:
Analytic_web.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path 

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'jas/', include('website.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

website.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'jas/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, '/templates/website/home.html' )
```

home.html:

```
<h1>Helllllllloooooooooowwwwwwwwwwwww</h1>
```

Comment: what link are you calling? I think that /jas/jas should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in website.urls.py, try :

```
path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

instead of this

```
path(r'jas/', views.home, name='home'),
```

and in Analytic_web.urls.py, try :

```
path('jas/', include('website.urls')),
```

instead of this

```
path(r'jas/', include('website.urls')),
```

hope this would help.